# How to get cart / quote programmatically without session?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, quote, programmatically

It's really common to get the quote with an existing session.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

But now I want to get the quote by **user** without any session (Magento 1.9). Do you have an advice for me?

Comment: Your only need if you want to load a quote without session is a customer, take a look at my answer.

Comment: @SimonSolutions In which place you want to get the quote? During checkout steps?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` class you can see the function `loadByCustomer`.
With that you only need a `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` object instance.

```
/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer **/
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
```

Answer (score 1):

If want to get `Cart/Quote` details then must  need Quote id.

Using `Mage::getModel('sales/quote')` Model with **help of Quote id**,you can get details

**Without Quote id is not possible to get data.**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the quote by customer with out session as below.

```
Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($this->_customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get it by customer_id, at least the data supports it but i doubt that it is possible with "normal magento model api" without a session.

Answer (score 0):

=> You can simply use load method of the model :

```
/*@var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote*/

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
```

It may be helpful for you.